# GraphQL query Invalid syntax error while testing on Postman. Springboot server

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, post, graphql

The springboot application exposes the graphql API on the endpoint "localhost:8091/rest/books". When I test it with Postman passing the query in the body as graphQL type it gives error "Invalid Syntax", whereas when I pass the same query as raw text, it yields correct results. I'm using HSQL. The structure of my application is:

[image]

The files with their code respectively are:

Book.java

```
package com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

//@AllArgsConstructor
//@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Table
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private String isn;
    public Book() {
        super();
    }
    public Book(String isn, String title, String publisher, String[] authors, String publishedDate) {
        super();
        this.isn = isn;
        this.title = title;
        this.publisher = publisher;
        this.authors = authors;
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }
    public String getIsn() {
        return isn;
    }
    public void setIsn(String isn) {
        this.isn = isn;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }
    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
    public String[] getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }
    public void setAuthors(String[] authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }
    public String getPublishedDate() {
        return publishedDate;
    }
    public void setPublishedDate(String publishedDate) {
        this.publishedDate = publishedDate;
    }
    private String title;
    private String publisher;
    private String[] authors;
    private String publishedDate;

}
```

BookRepository.java

```
package com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.repository;

import com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.model.Book;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, String> {
}
```

BookResource.java

```
package com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.resource;

import com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.service.GraphQLService;
import graphql.ExecutionResult;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping("/rest/books")
@RestController
public class BookResource {

    @Autowired
    GraphQLService graphQLService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllBooks(@RequestBody String query) {
        ExecutionResult execute = graphQLService.getGraphQL().execute(query);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(execute, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

AllBooksDataFetcher.java

```
package com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.service.datafetcher;

import com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.model.Book;
import com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.repository.BookRepository;
import graphql.schema.DataFetcher;
import graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class AllBooksDataFetcher implements DataFetcher<List<Book>>{

    @Autowired
    BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Book> get(DataFetchingEnvironment dataFetchingEnvironment) {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

BookDataFetcher.java

```
package com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.service.datafetcher;

import com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.model.Book;
import com.techprimers.graphql.springbootgrapqlexample.repository.BookRepository;
import graphql.schema.DataFetcher;
import graphql.schema.DataFetchingEnvironment;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class BookDataFetcher implements DataFetcher<Book>{

    @Autowired
    BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Override
    public Book get(DataFetchingEnvironment dataFetchingEnvironment) {

        String isn = dataFetchingEnvironment.getArgument("id");

        return bookRepository.findById(isn).get();
    }
}
```

And in the resources folder is
Books.graphql (contains schema)

```
schema {
 query: Query
}

type Query {
 allBooks: [Book]
 book(id: String): Book
}

type Book {
  isn: String
  title: String
  publisher: String
  authors: [String]
  publishedDate: String
}
```

Comment: ...raw? ... graphql works on json ... request/response content type

Comment: @xadm I mean, I just paste the query in the body section.. and before clicking "send", I can choose the type as "text" or "graphql". It works for type text, but not for type graphql.

Comment: I mean your server/API is not graphql specs compliant ... make it working with  `content-type 
application/json;`  ... how? I don't know, not using java at all

Comment: I think that's what it is too.